# Can't get logged into Stack Overflow site in Firefox on Linux

Tags: support, stack-overflow

```
Linux Fedora 17
Firefox 17.0.1
```

I can't seem to get logged into StackOverflow in Firefox.  I click the "login" link and am immediately given the "Welcome back, DCookie" message, but it does not log me in. I use a GMail account for logging in as a general rule. Clearly I get logged into this site; I also was able to get to dba.se. I can get logged in via the Chrome browser, no problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Clearing everything from Tools->Clear Recent History resolved the problem.

Thanks to team@stackexchange.com for the suggestion.

Comment: It still pisses me off that this works, ever. Mostly because I've never been able to reproduce it.